# Error creating bean with [name] Unsatisfied dependency through [field]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I am getting the following unsatisfied dependency error at run-time with my Spring MVC web app:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taskConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.myapps.todolist.main.DataSourceConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
```

`TaskConfig` is a JavaConfig class which has a dependency on `dataSource` (of type `DriverManagerDataSource`) which is configured in a separate JavaConfig class, `DataSourceConfig`.

**TaskConfig.java**

```
package com.myapps.todolist.main;

@Configuration
public class TaskConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TaskEntityDao taskEntityDao() 
    {
        TaskEntityDao taskEntityDao = new TaskEntityDaoImpl();
        taskEntityDao.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        return taskEntityDao;
    }
}
```

**DataSourceConfig.java**

```
package com.myapps.todolist.main;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyTable");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Why is TaskConfig unable to find the `DataSource` object?

My Spring config includes the following to scan for JavaConfig in the package that both those classes are in:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapps.todolist.main" />
```

**Update:** More of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.myapps.todolist.main.DataSourceConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
```

Comment: Can you upload complete error stake?

Comment: I guess you'll have to move the `@Bean` annotation in `DataSourceConfig` from the method head to the class head.

Comment: @Afridi I feel a bit stupid, as I didn't look at the stack trace properly. But I've added some more info from it - seems it's a problem with `DriverManagerDataSource` class not being found..

Comment: @petehallw yes, this exception occurs while creating bean with name "dataSource" due to missing class definition. So check your required maven dependencies. Except this, everything is working fine

Comment: 1st Exception: You need to import the `DataSourceConfig` into the `TaskConfig` to reference the bean. You can do something like `public TaskEntityDao taskEntityDao(DataSource ds)`. 2nd Exception: it is `NoClassDefFoundError`, what version of Spring are you using?

Comment: Please what are you even trying to achieve with TaskConfig.java class? I just can't get what's going on in that taskEntityDao bean.

Comment: @Perry There was a typo which has been corrected but it is just used to create a `DataSource` bean. It also has some other bean config that I didn't include as it didn't seem relevant for my question.
@RossiRobinsion Constructor DI is probably what I should be doing in this case. I believe just had to add a dependency in my pom file to get rid of the NoClassDefFoundError.